# Check duplicates column and print in another in bash

Tags: bash, awk, duplicates

Hi I need to do this in example bellow:

input file:

```
chr17   41246351    41246352    NM_007294_Exon_10
chr17   41246351    41246352    NM_007297_Exon_9
chr17   41246351    41246352    NM_007300_Exon_10
chr17   41246351    41246352    NR_027676_Exon_10
chr17   41246352    41246353    NM_007294_Exon_10
chr17   41246352    41246353    NM_007297_Exon_9
chr17   41246352    41246353    NM_007300_Exon_10
```

Get output like this:

```
chr17   41246351    41246352    NM_007294_Exon_10,NM_007297_Exon_9,NM_007300_Exon_10,NR_027676_Exon_10
chr17   41246352    41246353    NM_007294_Exon_10,NM_007297_Exon_9,NM_007300_Exon_10
```

I was try to use `uniq` and `sort`, but with no success. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '{i=$1 FS $2 FS $3} {a[i]=!a[i]?$4:a[i] FS $4} END {for (l in a) {print l,a[l]}}' file
```

If you want last column as comma separated,

```
awk '{i=$1 FS $2 FS $3} {a[i]=!a[i]?$4:a[i] "," $4} END {for (l in a) {print l,a[l]}}' file
```

Comment: Wau this is very nice solution. That looks it works perfectly fine to me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -ne '($k,$v)=/^(.*\s)(\S+)$/; $h{$k} .= "$v,";
            END{print "$_$h{$_}\n" foreach keys %h }' ip.txt
chr17   41246351    41246352    NM_007294_Exon_10,NM_007297_Exon_9,NM_007300_Exon_10,NR_027676_Exon_10,
chr17   41246352    41246353    NM_007294_Exon_10,NM_007297_Exon_9,NM_007300_Exon_10,
```

This leaves a trailing `,` though.. can be removed using `sed 's/,$//'`

Or use `?:` conditional to add comma as required (similar to logic used by @sat in awk solution), doesn't need post processing to remove trailing `,`

```
$ perl -ne '($k,$v)=/^(.*\s)(\S+)$/; $h{$k} .= $h{$k}?",$v":"$v";
            END{print "$_$h{$_}\n" foreach keys %h }' ip.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for perl solution. I have no experiences with perl, so I am very appreciate this lesson.

Answer (score 0):

try to use awk:

```
awk '!seen[$2]++' testfile
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Sploat thank you but this is normally uniq solution in awk, does not print what I need.